# What is the definitive way to use Gmail with OAuth and Nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, nodemailer

**Desired Behaviour**

Use `Gmail`, `OAuth2` and `Nodemailer` to send an email from a server side `node.js` file.

**What I've Tried**

*Relevant Documentation*

https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2
https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

*Relevant Questions*

[send emails from MY gmail account with OAuth2 and nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802598/send-emails-from-my-gmail-account-with-oauth2-and-nodemailer)
[How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936349
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22572776

There were gaps in the instructions of the above sources and some information was outdated, so the answer below was my final implementation which appears to be working.

I'm posting this solution for confirmation it is best practice and, if it is, to save others time.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The following worked for me, there are two parts:

**01)**   `app.js`

**02)**   `Google` and `OAuth2` setup

---

**app.js**

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: local_settings.my_gmail_username,
        clientId: local_settings.my_oauth_client_id,
        clientSecret: local_settings.my_oauth_client_secret,
        refreshToken: local_settings.my_oauth_refresh_token,
        accessToken: local_settings.my_oauth_access_token
    }
});


var mail = {
    from: "John Smith <me@mydomain.com>",
    to: "user@userdomain.com",
    subject: "Registration successful",
    text: "You successfully registered an account at www.mydomain.com",
    html: "<p>You successfully registered an account at www.mydomain.com</p>"
}

transporter.sendMail(mail, function(err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // see https://nodemailer.com/usage
        console.log("info.messageId: " + info.messageId);
        console.log("info.envelope: " + info.envelope);
        console.log("info.accepted: " + info.accepted);
        console.log("info.rejected: " + info.rejected);
        console.log("info.pending: " + info.pending);
        console.log("info.response: " + info.response);
    }
    transporter.close();
});
```

**Google and OAuth Setup**

The code above requires the following setup:

`01)`  Go to https://console.developers.google.com

`02)`  If you don't have a project, you will be prompted to create one

[image]

`03)`  Click on `Create Project`

`04)`  Click on `Create`

[image]
`05)`  Enter a `Project Name` and click `Create`

[image]

`06)`  Select the `Gmail API`

[image]

`07)`  Click on `Enable`

[image]

`08)`  Click on `Create Credentials`

[image]

`09)`  Enter the required settings

[image]

`10)`  Give the OAuth client a name and ensure you add `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground` as a `redirect URI` in order to generate the `refresh` and `access` tokens later

[image]
`11)`  Define the consent screen settings

[image]

`12)`  Click `I'll do this later` and `Done`

[image]

`13)`  Click on the `Edit` icon, to view your `Client ID` and `Client Secret`

[image]

`14)`  To generate `access` and `refresh` tokens, go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

`15)`  Click on the `cog` icon in the top right, check `Use your own OAuth credentials` and enter `Client ID` and `Client Secret`

[image]

`16)`  In the left column, select `Gmail API v1` and click `Authorise APIs`

[image]

`17)`  If you are signed into multiple accounts, when prompted select the relevant account

[image]

`18)`  Click `Allow`

[image]

`19)`  Click `Exchange authorisation code for tokens`

[image]
I'm not sure why there is a count down on the `access` token, but hopefully the message at the bottom of the screen means that the token won't expire.

Comment: Why do you call `transporter.close();`, is it needed for every email?

Comment: You save my day !!! This answer deserves more votes. Hand down for the best answer !!!

Comment: i wish i could give you 1000 upvotes, this was a huge help

Comment: This was so helpful! Thank you for posting it. Great instruction and totally worked for me.

Comment: This worked great with my G Suite account - However, I cant figure out how to make it work with my email aliases with my G Suite account! Do you know how I could send emails from the email alias of my account?

Comment: How do I create and submit a Oauth demo video for verification after this?

Comment: I just tried and it seems to work! (The UI changed a bit though.) What about the expiration of the token? The token is said to be temporary and to expire - what will happen when the token expires? Will I need to re-create the token every once in a while?

Comment: @brillout - a few people have mentioned this in the comments, and i can only speak from my experience implementing it as shown in the post, but two years after posting the solution it is still working for me, and i haven't had to recreate any token.

Comment: @user1063287 Actually in production (an AWS EC2 instance) Gmail doesn't send out any email, even though nodemailer gives me a `250 OK` response. It works on my local dev machine. Has anyone else also had problems in production?

Comment: @brillout - if it is working on dev machine, and nodemailer is giving the desired response in both dev and production environments, is it possible the issue is limited to the amazon environment, and therefore should be troubleshooted there (via amazon support ticket or even a new post on stack overflow detailing the issue)? my implementation is on red hat openshift and email is sending as desired.

Comment: If you're trying to use service accounts for this see : https://medium.com/@imre_7961/nodemailer-with-g-suite-oauth2-4c86049f778a . If you get "Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN" ... code: 'EAUTH', command: 'API'" check for typos

Comment: The refresh token can expire after 200 days. Also there is a send quota. If you want a large scale production solution, use amazon ses or mailgun or some proper smtp provider service

Comment: I know this is old, but I am currently going through this same headache, and I have already done exactly everything you showed, and I was able to send emails. But according to the Oauth documentation, if you are using an app in Testing state, ie. not a verified app, the refresh token expires every 7 days, and there is a maximum 50 refresh tokens per account. So this solution is kind of a band-aid as I am only wanting to use this to simply send an email from my website. I shouldn't need to verify an app to send an email from myself to myself. Now I'm trying to figure how to use a service acct

Comment: For token generation reference checkout this blog,

https://medium.com/@nickroach_50526/sending-emails-with-node-js-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-316fe9c790a1#:~:text=accessToken%20%3D%20oauth2Client.getAccessToken()

Answer (score 4):

### OAuth Consent Screen

You are definetely right about the gaps and outdated information, and you did a really great job on documenting the steps needed to use Gmail with OAuth and nodemailer!
Nevertheless, I think it worths mentioning that in the Credentials page there is another step: the **OAuth Consent Screen** tab.

It contains a form like a Google Play app submission that requires validation from Google, if you choose your app to not being validated, you have a limitation of 100 calls of what they call *Sensitive scopes* before being asked for submission.

#### What about quota?

It's still not clear to me if this 100 calls quota will be consumed even if you don't select any additional permission to use sensitive scopes (the default ones are email, profile, openid). I hope not, since the OAuth Consent Screen asks for things like the *Application Homepage Link* and *Authorised domains* that is something you might not have if you are working on a backend application.

I think that this whole procedure is really slow and uselessly complex since most people do all these steps to just send an email from their app using nodemailer...