# nodemailer OAuth2 gsuite (mail@example.com) serviceClient and privateKey config

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, nodemailer, google-gsuite

Nodemailer [documentation for 2LO](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#oauth-2lo) states you can make a config setup as such: **Note I'm using a web unique address example.com which is email-hosted with gsuite**:

```
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 465,
secure: true,
auth: {
  auth: 'OAuth2',
  user: 'mail@example.com',
  serviceClient: emailKey.client_id,
  privateKey: emailKey.private_key,
}
```

And you can make a gcp service account with the right config according to the [most up-to-date tutorial I can find](https://medium.com/@imre_7961/nodemailer-with-g-suite-oauth2-4c86049f778a). However it gives this error:

> Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN" ... code: 'EAUTH', command: 'API'

There are no solved issues on this, [here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/871) is one for reference.

All "Accepted answers" in related stack overflow questions I found are out of date since the JSON output from GCP service account no longer includes refresh and access tokens. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933601/what-is-the-definitive-way-to-use-gmail-with-oauth-and-nodemailer)
though looks like its gmail specific.

**Any recommendations? Am I required to use an access token set up? Because I couldn't find good documentation on how to do this. Perhaps the relevant google documentation, because I can't distinguish which is for unique web addresses and which is @gmail.com-specific.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed in `auth: 'OAuth2'` instead of `type: 'OAuth2'`